# JQuery / $.get is not displaying my data

Tags: jquery

In the example below, the alert dialog box is not displaying at all.  Any ideas why?

```
$.get('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Earth%20Day',function(data) { alert("DATA LOADED: " + data); });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your call is not working, is you are trying to make a cross-domain request with the normal `$.get` function of jQuery. You need to use `$.getJSON` and add `&callback=?` to the url so jQuery will treat it as a JSONP request:

```
$.getJSON(
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Earth%20Day&callback=?',
    function(data) { alert("DATA LOADED: " + data); }
);
```

You can also write your request this way to be a little more readable. Just remember the `callback=?` has to be in the URL and cannot be included in the object literal with the other key/value pairs:

```
$.getJSON(
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?callback=?',
    { v:'1.0', q:'Earth Day' },
    function(data) { alert("DATA LOADED: " + data); }
);
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't catch that myself :) Good eye, Doug.

Comment: I had to try his call myself from Firebug and then look up the documentation for both jQuery and Google. I was pretty sure that was the problem, but had to do my research first! Thanks man :)